# Python Regex: How to append string if found and append "Not Found" otherwise?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to append a result to a list if found, and append the string "N/A" to the list if no match is found. show_version_lists is a list of logs from various network devices.

```
import re

for result in show_version_list:

    for matchedtext in re.findall(r'(?<=Version).*?(?=-)',result)[:1]:

        if re.search(r'(?<=Version).*?(?=-)',result):

            version_numbers_xe.append(matchedtext)

        else:

            version_numbers_xe.append('n/a')
```

When I run the above code the else condition never occurs.

An Example of one of the logs that should match

```
Load for five secs: 5%/0%; one minute: 4%; five minutes: 4%
Time source is NTP, 15:24:47.756 PDT Thu Jun 16 2016
Cisco IOS XE Software, Version 03.16.01a.S - Extended Support Release
Cisco IOS Software, ASR1000 Software (PPC_LINUX_IOSD-ADVENTERPRISEK9-M), Version 15.5(3)S1a, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2015 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Wed 04-Nov-15 17:40 by mcpre
```

An Example of one of the logs that shouldn't match.

```
Cisco IOS Software, C3750E Software (C3750E-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version   15.2(2)E3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2015 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Wed 26-Aug-15 06:14 by prod_rel_team
```

Edit:

AChampion you were right taking out the for loop fixed the logic problem.

Comment: Your `re.findall()` call will only return matches, and you slice only the first match, so the `re.search()` will always be True. Can you share sample data? You might want to get rid of the `for` loop and `re.search()` and just use `re.match()`

Comment: else is never reached as re.findall and re.search are exactly same in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer).

finditer returns a match object, and we can use the re.group to append the version information from the match object. It's as simple as this.

```
import re

version_numbers_xe = []

for result in show_version_list:
    found = False
    for match in re.finditer(r'(?<=Version).*?(?=-)',result):
        version_numbers_xe.append(match.group())
        found = True
    if not found:
        version_numbers_xe.append(None)
```

I would recommend pre-compiling your regex, to product the following, for performance reasons:

```
import re

version_numbers_xe = []
version_regex = re.compile(r'(?<=Version).*?(?=-)')

for result in show_version_list:
    found = False
    for match in version_regex.finditer(result):
        version_numbers_xe.append(match.group())
        found = True
    if not found:
        version_numbers_xe.append(None)
```

This gets rid of the integrity check for the last match, but I'm not sure why you had it in the first place.

Comment: @J.Clark Finditer is also way better than using a findall for cases where you need to work with the match group afterwords. Especially if I want to look at the context of a match group, I often using finditer rather than findall.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your code logic. Your code is essentially saying the following:

For all the times you find regex result in matchedtext
*if you find the same regex result do x
*if not (which you always will) do y (so y never happens)

As an example, change the logic to something like:
For all the data in '*the source of* matchedtext'
if you find the regex result print x,
else print "n/a"